# Write/Read the image from fileSystemStorage and readjust it before saving

Tags: codenameone

I have saved an image using fileSystemStorage with the name of "profile.png". But how cab I read the image and display it afterward. I had used Storage.getInstance.writeObject and
readObject before but I think it doesnt work for images.

```
userImg.addActionListener((e) -> {
  Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            if (evt == null) {
                System.out.println("user cancelled");
                return;
            }
            eventImgpath = (String) evt.getSource();
            Image i = Image.createImage(eventImgpath);
            Image profileImg = i.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 3);

            InputStream stream = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(eventImgpath);
            OutputStream out = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("profile.png");
            Util.copy(stream, out);
            Util.cleanup(stream);
            Util.cleanup(out);

            userImg.setIcon(profileImg);
            userImg.setPreferredH(20 + Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth() / 3);
            userImg.getParent().revalidate();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
});
```

I have one more question. How can I re-adjust the image as an icon in a label? for eg we can readjust or drag to repostion cover img in facebook before saving it. Since it is a profile image while saving it sometime the face is not shown so I need to reposition the image and save it as a label icon. Is there any example for it?

Thankyou

Comment: The code you listed looks like it should work. Storage.writeObject/readObject serialize objects which is probably not what you want when dealing with images. It's unclear to me where the difficulty occurred?

Comment: yeah it works, I jst want to re-position the img. The problem I got is that when user saves his/her profile image, sometime the part of his/her face is cut out. So I want the functionality of repositioning the img. for eg we can reposition the cover img of facebook or profile pic too while uploading the image. Can we do that?

Comment: Is this on iOS only? If so we have a fix for an issue there that should already be available in current builds.

Comment: The app is going so well that I want it for both iOS and android... Isn't it available in android too? how can I achieve this feature? Do you have any tutorial, blog or example?

Comment: It should work for both. I was referring to a bug we recently fixed which I assumed you ran into but it's really unclear to me what you are seeing and where the problem is from the description? You posted working code but I still don't understand the problem. I suggest screenshots to illustrate the issue you are seeing as well as explanation on whether it is happening on simulator/android/ios or everywhere?